# Is the msvc datatype word signed or unsigned?

Tags: types, visual-c++

on a 32 bit machine:

```
typedef int word; 
or
typedef unsigned int word;
```

Comment: I don't know of MSVC type `word`. Actually I know something called `DWORD`.

Comment: In the beginning there was the WORD...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `windef.h`

```
typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
typedef int                 BOOL;
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
typedef unsigned short      WORD; // <--------
typedef float               FLOAT;
typedef FLOAT               *PFLOAT;
typedef BOOL near           *PBOOL;
typedef BOOL far            *LPBOOL;
typedef BYTE near           *PBYTE;
typedef BYTE far            *LPBYTE;
typedef int near            *PINT;
typedef int far             *LPINT;
typedef WORD near           *PWORD;
typedef WORD far            *LPWORD;
typedef long far            *LPLONG;
typedef DWORD near          *PDWORD;
typedef DWORD far           *LPDWORD;
typedef void far            *LPVOID;
typedef CONST void far      *LPCVOID;

typedef int                 INT;
typedef unsigned int        UINT;
typedef unsigned int        *PUINT;
```